# Creating and adding to dynamic arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying create a sign in userform for sports club that I help run but I am having trouble adding to a Dynamic Array.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim SignedInNames() As String
Dim NumberSignedIn As Integer
    NumberSignedIn = 1

ReDim SignedInNames(NumberSignedIn + 1)


Dim Names() As Variant
Names = Range("OFFSET('People Info'!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA('People Info'!$A:$A)-1,1)")

PersonNameComboBox.List = Names

SignedInListBox.List = SignedInNames
End Sub

Private Sub SignInCommandButton_Click()

SignedInNames = Add(PersonNameComboBox.Value) 'The code crashers here
NumberSignedIn = NumberSignedIn + 1

End Sub
```

I've changed it so now it is

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim SignedInNames() As String
Dim NumberSignedIn As Integer
    NumberSignedIn = 1

ReDim SignedInNames(0 To NumberSignedIn)


Dim Names() As Variant
Names = Range("OFFSET('People Info'!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA('People Info'!$A:$A)-1,1)")

PersonNameComboBox.List = Names

SignedInListBox.List = SignedInNames
End Sub

Private Sub SignInCommandButton_Click()

ReDim Preserve SignedInNames(0 To NumberSignedIn)
SignedInNames(NumberSignedIn) = PersonNameComboBox.Value
NumberSignedIn = NumberSignedIn + 1
'ReDim SignedInNames(o To NumberSignedIn)
SignedInListBox.List = SignedInNames
'SignedInNames = Add(PersonNameComboBox.Value)
'SignedInNames(NumberSignedIn) = PersonNameComboBox.Value
'NumberSignedIn = NumberSignedIn + 1

End Sub
```

I am now getting an error where when it gets to the line

```
ReDim Preserve SignedInNames(0 To NumberSignedIn)
```

it is showing the error "Variable not defined"

Comment: What's the actual error Excel throws?

Comment: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Comment: Where/when does that error appear? Does it give you a line number?

Comment: do you have `add` sub???

Comment: the code crashers on the line I marked with "'The Code Crashers here" and the code there is all the code I am using in that User Form

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation. Read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Your variables have local scope. You need to either make them global variables or pass them as arguments to `SignInCommandButton_Click()`

Comment: where do I add the indentations, I don't have any if, while, functions ect

Comment: @MatthewJohnston Actually, you can't pass them as arguments to that procedure because it's activated by clicking on a button. Just make them global by placing your `Dim...` lines at the top of your Module, outside of any procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the original problem by changing the way I setup the array. Then I fixed the second problem by making the variables I was using global.

```
Dim SignedInNames() As String
Dim NumberSignedIn As Integer
Dim Names() As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


NumberSignedIn = 1

ReDim SignedInNames(0 To NumberSignedIn)


Dim Names() As Variant
Names = Range("OFFSET('People Info'!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA('People Info'!$A:$A)-1,1)")

PersonNameComboBox.List = Names

SignedInListBox.List = SignedInNames
End Sub

Private Sub SignInCommandButton_Click()



ReDim Preserve SignedInNames(0 To NumberSignedIn)
SignedInNames(NumberSignedIn) = PersonNameComboBox.Value
NumberSignedIn = NumberSignedIn + 1
SignedInListBox.List = SignedInNames


End Sub
```